# "TEST" tab missing after upgrade to Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server

Tags: testing, tfs

After our upgrade the "TEST" tab is missing from TFS. Is this a common thing or am I missing something here?

[image: "TEST" missing next to "BUILD"]

Answer (score 6):

I would check your access level page http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses. Test Management is available at the Advanced level.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it. Our Admin added me to the FULL level and now I can see the tab. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You may need to re-configure features after TFS upgrade. Make 'Test Plat and Test Suite' feature is configured. See more details at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx

Comment: It claims "If you don't see the Configure Features link, your features have been enabled", I can't see the Configure Features link, but yet my "TEST" tab is still missing.